# How to use local filemanager to do a ssh -J (jump, gateway)

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, gateway, protocol

This is what I am trying to do. I want to connect to a server C, using a local file manager (nautilus, nemo, pcmanfm). I used to do this just writing

```
sftp://username@ServerC
```

in the location bar, or using connect to server option. However, now I am not anymore in the local network, then I need to pass first by a gate server. In the terminal, I do not have any problem jumping the gate server.

Doing

```
ssh -J gate ServerC
```

**The questions then are:**
How could I do this using the file manager?
Is there a way to write a kind of SFTP address considering initially the gate server?
Or to call back my local file manager from the terminal after connecting?

(Server C seems to not have file manager, I do not know if there is any systematic way to check this rather than looking each possible file manager at the time)

Answer (score 7):

GVFS (the common network-fs library used by Nautilus and Nemo) creates its SFTP connections using the regular `ssh` tool as the transport.

The *ssh* manual page says that `-J` is a shortcut for the `ProxyJump` option. You can specify this option permanently in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host ServerC
   ProxyJump gate
```

Comment: Thanks, excellent solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to terminal file managers, `nnn` can handle options specified like:

```
sshfs -o ProxyJump=gate,reconnect,idmap=user,cache_timeout=3600
```

So if you are temporarily out of your local network, you can skip making changes in the `~/.ssh/config`.

Other than that, it can also pick up ssh configurations from `~/.ssh/config` directly as @user1686 answered. It saves on typing as well. All you need to provide is the host (and password if any).