# Specify key exchange protocol with lftp

Tags: sftp, lftp

I have to download some (large) data from a distant server.

The remote IT people suggest using `lftp sftp://user@server.domain:port`.

However, when I type `ls`, I read:

```
`ls' at 0 [Unable to negotiate with XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port PPP: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
```

It seems that they cannot change their key exchange method now (yes, I know, it is subject to attack, I warned them).

So I used:

```
sftp -P port -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@server.domain
```

I type `get -a -r *`, but I now have problem with symlinks, which are poorly handled by `sftp` (as far as I know).

What are my options now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both lftp and sftp use /usr/bin/ssh as the transport – they let the SSH client establish the connection (starting the SFTP responder instead of an interactive shell) and only speak the SFTP protocol over stdin/stdout. Many other programs such as [GVFS](https://superuser.com/q/1515190), rsync, Git, Borg, etc. also work the same way.

You can use `~/.ssh/config` to specify custom settings that apply to all programs which invoke 'ssh':

```
Host server.domain
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

Comment: Tested.  Works like a charm.